# Как в CSS все относительные пути привести к одному виду?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В CSS-файле есть строки:

```
background: url(../../path/image1.png);
background: url(../../../path/image2.png);
background: url(../../../path/image3.png);
```

Как все пути привести к одному виду:

```
background: url(../path/image1.png);
background: url(../path/image2.png);
background: url(../path/image3.png);
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mzm5mT/4 Вроде как подходит, набросал на скорую руку

Comment: Если точно не знаем какие папки и форматы, можно так: `\.\.\/\w+\/.*\.\w+`

Comment: Папки не знаем, нужно просто все такие штуки ../../../ заменить на одиночную ../

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '
    background: url(../../path/image1.png);
    background: url(../../../path/image2.png);
    background: url(../../../path/image3.png);
';

echo preg_replace('/\(\K[\/.]+/', '../', $string);
```

https://3v4l.org/hkjsm